# Equality for cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I need to get the cases when exactly  (A $\cup$ B) × (C $\cup$ D) $\subset$ (AxC) $\cup$ (BxD)

I have proved it everything that I did seems logical so I wanted to get a second opinion on my work here is my proof:

To show equality we first simplify

(A $\cup$ B) x (C $\cup$ D) = (AxC) $\cup$ (AxD) $\cup$ (BxC) $\cup$ (BxD)

to get equality we need
(AxC) $\cup$ (AxD) $\cup$ (BxC) $\cup$ (BxD)  = (AxC) $\cup$ (BxD)

This happens iff (BxC) $\cup$ (AxD) $\subset$ (AxC) $\cup$ (BxD)

Hence we need to prove  when 
(AxD) $\cup$ (BxC) $\subset$ (AxC) $\cup$ (BxD)

this is same as proving

(A $\cup$ B) x (A $\cup$ C) x (D $\cup$ B) x (D $\cup$ C) $\subset$  (A $\cup$ B) x (A $\cup$ D) x (C $\cup$ B) x (C $\cup$ D)

Since (A $\cup$ B) and (C $\cup$ B) is already subset of the right side all we need to prove is when

(A $\cup$ C) x (D $\cup$ B) $\subset$ (A $\cup$ D) x (C $\cup$ B) 
case 1:
A = B is one case since
(B $\cup$ C) x ( D $\cup$ A) $\subset$ (A $\cup$ D) x (C $\cup$ B)

case 2:
Other case is D = C since
(A $\cup$ D) x (C $\cup$ B) $\subset$ (A $\cup$ D) x (C $\cup$ B)

case 3:
C $\subset D$ AND B $\subset$ A

Since (A $\cup$ C) $\subset$ (A $\cup$ D)  AND (D $\cup$ B) $\subset$ (A $\cup$ D)

case 4:
D $\subset$ C AND  A $\subset$ B similar argument

Comment: The tex command for $\cup$ is $\backslash$cup.

Comment: 1 moment will edit all of them !

Comment: Gregory Grant any comment for the proof ?

Comment: I found counter example to my proof and one can see it graphically but I don't know why my proof is wrong which step has logical inconsistencies ? I am expecting graphically it should be $A \subset B$ AND $C \subset D$ and vice versa but my proof doesn't show that....!

Comment: Where you say "this is the same as proving" I think the following line is problematic.  That is now a statement about 4-dimensional  space which I don't think follows from the previous.

Comment: which line are you referring to Gregory Grant?

Comment: (A $\cup$ B) x (A $\cup$ C) x (D $\cup$ B) x (D $\cup$ C) $\subset$  (A $\cup$ B) x (A $\cup$ D) x (C $\cup$ B) x (C $\cup$ D)

Comment: I just foiled the cartesian product I thought it had this property so I can do that

Comment: Yes but (AxC) $\cup$ (BxD) is not equal to 
(A $\cup$ B) x (A $\cup$ D) x (C $\cup$ B) x (C $\cup$ D) (they can't be because they live in different dimensions).
So when you say it's the same thing to prove both statements that is certainly not obvious.  Are you sure it is true?

Comment: Also when you say (A $\cup$ B) and (C $\cup$ B) are already a subset of the right hand side, that doesn't make sense, again because the two things live in different dimensions, the right hand side is in two dimensions while (A $\cup$ B) is in one dimension.

Comment: I see yeah well I needed to get the cases where exactly equality occurs I was able to do it graphically that is I considered [(AxC) $\cup$ (BxD)] - [(AxC)$\cup$(BxD)] = [(A - B) x (D - C)] $\cup$ [(B - A) $\cup$ (C - D)] hence we get equality when that is equal to the empty set. It follows then we get empty set exactly when (A - B)x(D - C) = $\phi$ and (B - A) x( C - D) = $\phi$ Hence one case is A $\subset$ B then we must have C $\subset$ D and the other case follows similiarly.

Comment: I wanted however to do it directly but I keep getting bigger and bigger terms yeh my above argument is vague.